# Turtle will not draw angled lines

Tags: python

[Circle cursor picture error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9M0b.png)  I am having problems drawing angle lines with turtle. I can make squares, but star shapes do not show up. Also, the triangular cursor only shows one line, a circle cursor shows 4 horizontal lines. If I switch to "turtle" shape - it just shows 5 dots. See attached pic.

here's a simple star prog

```
import turtle 

star = turtle.Turtle()

for i in range(50):
    star.forward(50)
    star.right(144)

turtle.done()
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.  Please review [ask] and [mcve] as your question currently doesn't have enough details to be answerable.  Suggested example would be the quote you're using to draw a star shape.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on openSUSE Leap 43.3 and solved it by installing the correct graphics driver (in my case, xf86-video-intel on a Thinkpad T510).