# How to create circle and triangle with specific colour using turtle in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle
import math
import random
import os`

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("yellow")
player.shape("triangle")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)`

maxGoals = 10
goals = []

for count in range(maxGoals):
    goals.append(turtle.Turtle())
    goals[count].color("red")
    goals[count].shape("circle")
    goals[count].penup()
    goals[count].speed(0)
    goals[count].setposition(random.randint(-290,290),random.randint(-290,290))`
```

When run this code i am getting only the `circle's outline in Red color` and  the `triangle's outline in Yellow color`

I need the `circle filled with red color`and the `triangle filled with Blue color`.  I have included the image below:

[image: Here the circle's outline is in red colour and triangle's outline is in Yellow color]

Kindly help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

I ran the code provided by you and it is working just fine. Please try the same code on the different machine and provide details so that if this is a system specific problem, I'll be able to help you if you provide moreinformation.

I ran it using a mac, python 2.7
[image: python program output]

joginder

Comment: Yeah you are right it works fine with mac. I am using `Ubuntu 16.10 with python 2.7` linux OS. Here it is showing only the outline as I mentioned in the screenshot .kindly help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has come up several times on SO, but unfortunately, I can only locate one this morning: [Turtle will not draw angled lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36664329/5771269)

The answer *always* seems to be that it's a graphics driver issue. Once corrected, things start working as expected.  Sorry I can't be more specific but it depends on your system's setup.