# Turtle graphics in python does not work correctly

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to execute the following code from the fourth chapter of the book "How to Think Like a Computer Scientist"
But it seems that the turtle object does not draw the sloped squares.

```
import turtle

def draw_multicolor_square(t, sz):
    """Make turtle t draw a multi-color square of sz."""
    for i in ["red", "purple", "hotpink", "blue"]:
        t.color(i)
        t.forward(sz)
        t.left(90)

wn = turtle.Screen()        # Set up the window and its attributes
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")

tess = turtle.Turtle()      # Create tess and set some attributes
tess.pensize(3)

size = 20                   # Size of the smallest square
for i in range(15):
    draw_multicolor_square(tess, size)
    size = size + 10        # Increase the size for next time
    tess.forward(10)        # Move tess along a little
    tess.right(18)          #    and give her some turn

wn.mainloop()
```

I expect several squares but it only draws 3 squares without slopes.

Comment: Apart from having nausea inducing colours, your code works fine on my computer.      What version of python are you using ? `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: 3.5.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May 13 2018, 21:27:04) 
[GCC 7.2.0]

Answer (score 0):

There may be some issues with turtle on anaconda.  I found this post on another site:

Call turtle.done() with turtle.bye() and use the Inline or Automatic backend for the IPython Console (Preferences > IPython Console > Graphics > Graphics Backend). As an example:

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6278

Comment: The link appears to deal with an issue running code at all a second time under Anaconda, not about missing graphics elements in a program that successfully runs.

Answer (score 0):

If you only see three squares, it means your turtle graphics isn't showing slanted lines, only horizontal and vertical.  This has come up several times before, for example: [Turtle will not draw angled lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36664329/5771269)

The answer always seems to be, "it's a graphics driver issue". Once the graphics card driver issue is corrected, things start working as expected. I can't be more specific, as it depends on *your* system's setup.